# How do I bind ion-checkbox to standalone [formControl]?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Current behaviour:
Putting the [formControl] on the checkbox itself gives no error but destroying and creating the component does not save it's state. Putting [formControl] on ion-item has same effect.On the list I get 'no value accessor.'

Expected Behaviour:
Selecting an item passes the value through the checkbox and changes the value of the FormControl, saving the state.

Notes:
Reactive Forms Module IS imported in the app.module.ts, onSelectionChange does not work either.

**menu.ts**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Company, Counter, CounterGroup } from '../index/counter-groups.model';
import { IndexService } from '../index/index.service';
import { LoaderService } from '../loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss'],
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  counterGroups: Array<CounterGroup> = [];
  selectedCounterGroup: CounterGroup;

  sub: Subscription;

  selectedCounters: FormControl = new FormControl('');

  constructor(
    private indexService: IndexService,
    private ionLoader: LoaderService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.indexService.fetchCounterGroups().subscribe((asd) => {
      this.counterGroups = asd.counterGroups;
      this.selectedCounterGroup = this.counterGroups[0]
    });

    this.sub = this.selectedCounters.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
      console.log(v);
    });
  }

  onSelectionChange($event, i) {
    console.log(' ~ onSelectionChange ~ i', i);
    console.log(' ~ onSelectionChange ~ $event', $event);
  }
}
```

**menu.html**

```html
<ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="for_page">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list [formControl]="selectedCounters">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let counter of selectedCounterGroup.counters">
        <ion-checkbox
          slot="end"
          (ionChange)="onSelectionChange($event, i)"
          [value]="counter.id"
        ></ion-checkbox>
        <ion-label>{{ counter.name }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

Comment: Workaround is use  `PatchValue`  in `onSelectionChange` function. E.g: `onSelectionChange($event, i){ this.yourFromGroup.patchValue({ selectedCounters: $event.target.value }) }` check exactly what's inside $event.

Comment: Thing is, onSelectionChange is not even being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try ngModel

```
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="yourCheckbox"
              class="your-class-checkbox">
</ion-checkbox
```